# How was Red Skull where the Soul Stone was in Avengers: Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, why was Red Skull where the Soul Stone was with the knowledge of the Soul Stone?